# Receiving a TypeError: "option is undefined" error message

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu

My dropdown menu seemed to be working fine and now I'm receiving this error, seemingly, out of nowhere. I've tried changing quite a few things in here and can't seem to figure this one out. Is the data type wrong or am I simply calling something funky?

I would appreciate any insight as to what I'm not seeing here!

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Deposit Holder</label>
      <v-select
              class="highlights"
              :options="select.offices"
              :on-change="selectOffice"
              :searchable="false"
              :clear-search-on-select="false"
              v-model="select.officeSelected"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
  </div>

 data() {
  return {
    now: new Date().toISOString(),
    loaded: false,
    document: {
      office_id: null,
    },
    select: {
      offices: [
        {
          'value': 1,
          'label': 'Nu World Title Kendall',
        },
        {
          'value': 2,
          'label': 'Nu World Title KW Kendall Office',
        },
        {
          'value': 3,
          'label': 'Nu World Title Miramar',
        },
        {
          'value': 4,
          'label': 'Nu World Title Davie',
        },
        {
          'value': 5,
          'label': 'Nu World Title Doral',
        },
        {
          'value': 6,
          'label': 'Nu World Title Miami Lakes',
        },
        {
          'value': 7,
          'label': 'Sanchez Vadillo Coral Gables',
        }
      ],
      officeSelected: '',
    }

methods: {
  selectOffice(option) {
    this.select.officeSelected = option;
    this.document.office_id = option.value;
  },

mounted() {
  this.selectOffice();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In `mounted` you're calling `this.selectOffice()` but not passing it any parameters. The method `selectOffice` is then trying to access `option.value` but as you haven't passed anything `option` will be `undefined`.

I would have expected a stack trace to accompany that error message, which would have indicated which functions were involved in causing the problem.

Comment: When you don't pass any parameters to a function with declared variables they're undefined by default.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  So, how exactly would I do that? I'm totally discombobulated here.

Comment: @johnconley Not sure why you're calling `selectOffice` in the first place but you'd need to pass it a suitable `option`. e.g. `this.selectOffice(this.select.offices[0])`. However, to reiterate, I don't actually know what you're trying to achieve when you call `selectOffice` inside your `mounted` hook. What you need to pass depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @skirtle I'm trying to have a dropdown, with these options (preferably with the first one showing by default)

Comment: That worked. I think I see what you mean now. @skirtle